# Using filter function with alphanumeric data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I have a sheet of students and the classroom numbers that they visit throughout the day.
I am trying to use a filter formula that returns the name of any student in a specified classroom. However, the classrooms are alphanumeric (eg: A-10, A-11, A-12).

I am using the below formula. When the room numbers are just numbers, the filter works and returns the students name, but when there is a letter in the room number, it is returning this error: "No matches are found in FILTER evaluation."

Column A contains student names,
Columns C-J contain the classrooms that student attends
and R3 is an formula the pulls up the desired room number.

`=FILTER($A6:$A,($C6:$C=R3)+($D6:$D=R3)+($E6:$E=R3)+($F6:$F=R3)+($G6:$G=R3)+($H6:$H=R3)+($I6:$I=R3)+($J6:$J=R3)))`

[image: Classrooms]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. The image has merged cells and doesn't include the row headers so it's unclear if the formulas was properly set. Please try to reproduce the problem in a smaller area and update the image an formulas incluiding all the relevant details. Also it might be helpful if you include the data as text rather as an image and/or share a spreadsheet to make other reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `filter()` formula you show seems fine. Since it cannot find any results, chances are that the values in `R3:3` do not match the values in `C6:J`.

Row numbers are not shown, so it is possible that the correct range is actually `R2:2`. Try this formula in a free cell:

`="R3: " & R3, ", C6: " & C6, ", match? " & R3 = C6`

Even if the values look the same, they can still differ because of trailing spaces and the like. Check the formula you have in `R3`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

The formula you gave is also returning an error. I have attached row numbers. The formula in R3 is: 


=SPLIT(ArrayFormula(JOIN(" , , ,",FILTER(O6:O,P6:P>2))),",")


I have updated the screen shot to show row numbers as well as the reference for the R3 formula

Comment: As suspected, there are trailing spaces in the values in `R3:3`. The problem is with the `join()` delimiter that includes a space. Remove the space to make it work. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks so much

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)